# Embed a word menu in OleContainer

Tags: user-interface, delphi, ms-word

I use an oleContainer to embed a Word document.
That worked out so far. However, the menu is outside the oleContainer.
As you can see in this picture.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I get the menu into the container?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.OleCtnrs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    OleContainer1: TOleContainer;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses ComObj, shellapi;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FDocument, FWord:Variant;
  FContainer: TOleContainer;
begin
  FContainer := TOleContainer.Create(olecontainer1);
  FContainer.Modified := false;
  FContainer.Parent := olecontainer1;
  FContainer.Align := alClient;
  FContainer.CreateObject('Word.Document', true);
  FDocument := IDispatch(FContainer.OleObject);
  FWord := FDocument.Application;
  FContainer.DoVerb(ovShow);
end;

end.
```